# Trying to call an AJAX function and then refresh the related component in Next.js

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to call an async function that gets data from an API call.
i've got it to run before the page loads and it works
but i want to be able to press a button that runs the same function again

i think the problem is that the function and the component displaying the data is a server component while the button is a client component

heres the code:

app/page.js

```
import CarCard from './components/CarCard';
import AjaxButton from './components/AjaxButton';
import { getData } from './actions'

export default async function Page(props) {
  //const cars = ["Golf GTI", "BMW I4 M50", "BMW 325i"];
  props.cars = await getData()
  
  return (
    <div style={{height:100+'%',width:100+'%',backgroundColor:'inherit'}}>
      <h1 class="mb-4 text-4xl font-extrabold leading-none tracking-tight text-gray-900 md:text-5xl lg:text-6xl dark:text-white text-center">
        Bobat Family Garage
      </h1>


      <AjaxButton onClick="getData" text="REFRESH"/>

      <div class="flex flex-col justify-around" style={{height:100+'%'}}>
        {props.cars.map((car,index)=>{
          return <CarCard carName={car} />
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

app/components/AjaxButton.js

```
'use client'
 
import { useTransition } from 'react'
import { getData } from '../actions'

const AjaxButton = ({ onClick, text }) => {
    let [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition()

    return <main>{
      <button onClick={() => getData()}>
      { text }
      </button>
      
    }</main>;
};

export default AjaxButton;
```

app/actions.js

```
'use server'

export async function getData() {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8090/car')
    // The return value is *not* serialized
    // You can return Date, Map, Set, etc.
   
    if (!res.ok) {
      // This will activate the closest `error.js` Error Boundary
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
    }
   
    return res.json()
  }
```

I want to be able to press the button and it goes off and gets the data in an AJAX call and refresh the  CarCard components, presumably by updating whats in props.cars

Also if you have any more suggestions, please let me know, i'm new to React Frameworks